# How to set/unset values of columns filters in Excel using apache POI in JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet with filters added to all of its columns. I want to unset/set some values of filters using apache POI JAVA. I have tried a lot of things but in vain. Any help will be appreciated.

[Unset few values in the following filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUDwF.png)
[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkhf0.png)

Comment: You have to post a code.

Comment: I would have done If I had any idea about it. Though I can read and write excel file. There was no relevant code that I could post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until now this can only be achieved using the underlaying low level objects of `apache poi`. For `AutoFilter`these are  [org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTAutoFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTAutoFilter.java) and successors.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTAutoFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilterColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STFilterOperator;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class AutoFilterSetTest {

 private static void setCellData(Sheet sheet) {
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("Number");
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("Alphabets");

  for (int r = 1; r < 11; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue(r);
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue(new String(Character.toChars(64 + r)));
  }
 }

 private static void setCriteriaFilter(XSSFSheet sheet, int colId, int firstRow, int lastRow, String[] criteria) throws Exception {
  CTAutoFilter ctAutoFilter = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter();
  CTFilterColumn ctFilterColumn = null;
  for (CTFilterColumn filterColumn : ctAutoFilter.getFilterColumnList()) {
   if (filterColumn.getColId() == colId) ctFilterColumn = filterColumn;
  }
  if (ctFilterColumn == null) ctFilterColumn = ctAutoFilter.addNewFilterColumn();
  ctFilterColumn.setColId(colId);
  if (ctFilterColumn.isSetFilters()) ctFilterColumn.unsetFilters();

  CTFilters ctFilters = ctFilterColumn.addNewFilters();
  for (int i = 0; i < criteria.length; i++) {
   ctFilters.addNewFilter().setVal(criteria[i]);
  }

  //hiding the rows not matching the criterias
  DataFormatter dataformatter = new DataFormatter();
  for (int r = firstRow; r <= lastRow; r++) {
   XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
   boolean hidden = true;
   for (int i = 0; i < criteria.length; i++) {
    String cellValue = dataformatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(colId));
    if (criteria[i].equals(cellValue)) hidden = false;
   }
   if (hidden) {
    row.getCTRow().setHidden(hidden);
   } else {
    if (row.getCTRow().getHidden()) row.getCTRow().unsetHidden();
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

  //create rows of data
  setCellData(sheet);

  for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);

  int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  XSSFAutoFilter autofilter = sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(0, lastRow, 0, 1));
  //XSSFAutoFilter is useless until now

  setCriteriaFilter(sheet, 0, 1, lastRow, new String[]{"2", "4", "7"});

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("AutoFilterSetTest.xlsx");
  wb.write(out);
  out.close();
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in [Frequently Asked Questions](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025). This is because the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CT*Filter*` classes are not included in the smaller `poi-ooxml-schemas jar`  which is shipped with `apache poi` by default.

---

This code works further using current Apache POI version 5.2.3. It needs the full jar of all of the schemas `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3.jar` as mentioned in [Frequently Asked Questions](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

And Grepcode is dead. So there is no API documentation for `org.openxmlformats.schemas.*` classes public available. But one can download the sources of `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3` (for example from here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-full/5.2.3/). Then one can do `javadoc` from those sources to create a API documentation. There you will find API documentation for `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CT*Filter*` classes.

Comment: Thanks! Although it works fine, but it is only available in latest poi version, I guess.

Comment: @Parthenophobic Sallu: No. This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in [Frequently Asked Questions](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. Also, I wanted to know why is using low level objects not considered a good practice?

Comment: @Parthenophobic Sallu: "Why is using low level objects not considered a good practice?": `Apache poi`is highly in development and so the [XSSFAutoFilter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFAutoFilter.html) will have appropriate methods in shorter future. And then the code which does not using this methods will be outdated. So code which uses low level objects will need to be updated periodically.  But the development of `apache poi`is not really considering downwards compatibility. So this is also true if you are using only the high level `apache poi` classes.

Comment: Could we make "Text Filters" to point to other option, such as "Begins With..." programmatically? It shows "equals" with the code above.

Comment: @niaomingjian: This example sets a criteria filter. What you are describing is a custom filter "abc*". This is another different problem. So this also should be another different question.