# Uncheck filter values using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using apache poi to generate a spreadsheet with auto filter enabled using the following code

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:N1"));
```

Now, I need to be able to uncheck (deselect) some of the filter values for a given column;

[image]

We have a similar question here [How to set/unset values of columns filters in Excel using apache POI in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997351/how-to-set-unset-values-of-columns-filters-in-excel-using-apache-poi-in-java) but since it's a bit old I was wondering if we have a better approach for this today.

Comment: "I was wondering if we have a better approach for this today": Unfortunately not. My statement: "XSSFAutoFilter is useless until now" stays. See [public interface AutoFilter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/AutoFilter.html) and [public final class XSSFAutoFilter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFAutoFilter.html). It has no members nor methods.